# NGXS Selector observable not getting new state

Tags: angular, observable, state, ngxs

When i update the state my selector isnt pulling the new values.
I have created the selector in my state and i can see the state values being updated, but
my selector on my component isn't pulling the newest values. i can see the console log has th newest values and that the state is updating in the browser plugin. however on my componenet the observable does not fire with the newest values.

```
@State<CompleteUser>(
    {
        name: 'auth',
        defaults: { 
            'user': {
            },
            'userAuth':{
            },
            'usersLocation':{
            },
            'following':[],
            'followers':[],
            'chats':[],
            'favoritePosts':[],
            'favoritePlaces': [],
            'charges': []
        }
    }   
)

export class AuthState {


    @Selector() 
    static user(state: CompleteUser){
        return state.user;
    }

    @Action(
        GetProfile
    )
    GetProfile(
        ctx: StateContext<CompleteUser>,
        uid: any
    ) {
        const state = ctx.getState();
        console.log('Uid ' + uid);
        this.auth.getUsersProfile(
            uid.uid
        ).pipe(
            tap(
                (usersProfile:User) => {
                    console.log('Users profile ', usersProfile);
                    if(usersProfile.alertsAmount && usersProfile.alertsAmount > 0){
                        this.badge.set(usersProfile.alertsAmount);
                    }
                    state.user = usersProfile;
                    ctx.patchState(
                        {   ...state,
                            user: state.user
                        }
                    );
                }
            )
        ).subscribe();
    }
}
```

my selector observable is as follows

```
  @Select(AuthState.user) user$: Observable<User>;


    this.liveData = combineLatest(
      this.currentShoots$,
      this.user$,
      this.usersLocation$
    );
 this.pageSub = combineLatest(
      this.liveData
    ).subscribe();
```

Comment: Sounds like the `GetProfile` action is getting dispatched, so you might be getting tripped up on `combineLatest` - `this.liveData` won't emit anything until all 3 combined observables have emitted at least once

Comment: Might be handy to show us how `this.liveData` and `this.pageSub` are being used in the component template

Answer (score 2):

Just return the stream in your action handler. NGXS will subscribe to it for you:

```
@Action(
    GetProfile
)
GetProfile(
    ctx: StateContext<CompleteUser>,
    uid: any
) {
    const state = ctx.getState();
    console.log('Uid ' + uid);
    return this.auth.getUsersProfile(  // <--- add return statement
        uid.uid
    ).pipe(
        tap(
            (usersProfile:User) => {
                console.log('Users profile ', usersProfile);
                if(usersProfile.alertsAmount && usersProfile.alertsAmount > 0){
                    this.badge.set(usersProfile.alertsAmount);
                }
                state.user = usersProfile;
                ctx.patchState(
                    {   ...state,
                        user: state.user
                    }
                );
            }
        )
    ); // <-- remove subscribe() call 
}
```

Also, just my opinion, but you could condense your code, you don't actually need to getState... you really only need to patchState:

```
@Action(GetProfile)
GetProfile({ patchState }: StateContext<CompleteUser>, uid: any) {
  return this.auth.getUsersProfile(uid.uid).pipe(
    tap((usersProfile: User) => {
      if (usersProfile.alertsAmount && usersProfile.alertsAmount > 0) {
        this.badge.set(usersProfile.alertsAmount);
      }
      // state.user = usersProfile; <-- Don't do this
      patchState({ user: usersProfile });
    }),
  );
}
```